# Skip SonarQube sensors during scan

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner

I have a project which does not need below sensors to go through during sonarqube scan:
INFO: Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco]
INFO: Java-based frontend sensor [javascript]

Is there a way skip or deactivate couple of sensors for few projects during sonarscan?

Appreciate your response.